# what should do if system does not support intel x86 for android emulator and ARM EABI?

Tags: android

I have system with Intel core 2 duo@2.00 GHz processor, 4 GB ram specs. Processor does't support Intel x 86 accelerator, what should i do?
please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Windows 8. Android Studio.
Make sure if virtualization is enable : go through those steps provided below.
```

- Goto setting -> change pc settings-> general->then see on right side
  by scrolling the frame down-> you will see under advance start up
  restart now button press it->then choose an option window will
  open->choose troubleshoot->under troubleshoot choose Advance
  option->then under Advance options choose UEFI Firmware option->then
  press restart->press f10 for BIOS->see the menubar where you will
  find system configuration menu inside it you will see the
  virtualization Technology "enable" it ->now go for exit saving
  changes in exit on menu bar..

  C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm-android.exe

  (in username : please enter valid user name)

  install it and restart your Android Studio.

  for win 7 and eclipse only little changes/no changes will do, have fun!!